# Is an ideal invariant for the adjoint action?

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a (compact)  matrix Lie group and let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the associated Lie algebra of $G$. Then is an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$ an invariant subspace for the adjoint action $\text{Ad}:G\rightarrow \text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ (where $\text{Ad}_A(X)=AXA^{-1}$ for $A \in G$ and $X \in \mathfrak{g}$)?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1723454/96384

Comment: Thank you. I already know that it is true if $G$ is connected (the above question assumed the connectedness for an algebraic group, and I am considering matrix Lie group over complex i.e. the characteristic is zero). My problem will be, in detail, that 
the given $G$ is not necessary connected, I think.

Comment: Noted. Once, I explain about the connected case. If $G$ is connected, then every element of $G$ can be written in the form $$e^{X_1}...e^{X_2}$$ where $X_i$'s lie in the Lie algebra of $G$. Furthermore, we have the relation $$\text{Ad}_{e^X}=e^{\text{ad}_X}.$$ So, since an ideal $\mathfrak{h}$ is ad-invariant, the two fact tell us that $\mathfrak{h}$ is also Ad-invariant, as claimed.